# Android -Getting weird error on Implementing BottomNavigation View with ViewPager attached to it in BottomSheetDialog Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, bottom-sheet

I have a **BottomSheetDialogFragment**, TicketDashboard which has following code

Injecting views with ButterKnife, getting error when setting adapter to ViewPager. Error says no view available for **R.id.ticket_dashboard_view_pager**. Stacktrace attached at end.

```
@Bind(R.id.ticket_dashboard_view_pager)
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
    View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_ticket_dashboard, null);
    dialog.setContentView(contentView);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, contentView);

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();

    if( behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior ) {
        mBottomSheetBehavior = (BottomSheetBehavior) behavior;
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(470);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    mToolBar.setTitle("Ticket# " + ticket.getTicketNumber());
    mToolBar.setNavigationIcon(getActivity().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_upward_white_24dp));
    mToolBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(isExpanded) {
                mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
            }else{
                mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            }
        }
    });
    setupViewPager();
    mBottomNavigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
}

private void setupViewPager(){
    setUpPages();
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    **mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);** // Line at which iam getting error
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
}
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:design="http://schema.android.com/apk/res/android.support.design"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

//ToolBar

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/ticket_dashboard_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_layout"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
    app:menu="@menu/ticket_dashboard_menu" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

StackTrace

> Process: io.webguru.ticketing, PID: 29663
>                                                                         java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0f01ca
>   (io.webguru.ticketing:id/ticket_dashboard_view_pager) for fragment
>   TicketOverviewFragment{bb97f0f #4 id=0x7f0f01ca}

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace getFragmentManager with getChildFragmentManager()

```
private void setupViewPager(){
    setUpPages();
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    **mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);** // Line at which iam getting error
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
}
```

Comment: i tried with getChildFragmentManager() but getting this error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment does not have a view
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment$2.onFindViewById(Fragment.java:2159)`

Comment: Check my answer. Do in onCreateView instead of setUpDialog. if you use view pager then there are lots of bugs in bottomsheetdialogfragment. Later if you want to use RecyclerView in Viewpager Fragment then there is another bugs which dont allow you to scroll the recyclerView (Except the first scrollView). :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inflating layout on setUpDialog, do in onCreateView

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_trophy, null);

        initUI(mContentView);

        mContentView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) getDialog();

                        FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) dialog.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
                        mBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);

                        if (mBehavior != null && mBehavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
                            mBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
                            int height = LayoutUtils.getScreenHeight(getActivity());
                            final double desiredHeight = PurchaseConstants.SLIDING_ANCHOR_POINT * height;
                            mContentView.getLayoutParams().height = height;
                            mBehavior.setPeekHeight((int) desiredHeight);
                        }
                    }


                });

        return mContentView;
    }
```